# React Native Event

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a TextInput component that calls an 'OnChangeText' event :

```
<TextInput onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({zip:text})}/>
```

That works fine.

Now I want to change the call event to a function:

```
 <TextInput onChangeText={_handleTextChange}/>

_handleTextChange(event) {
       this.setState({zip: 
       event.nativeEvent.text});

  }
```

That doesn't work. I get the following error :

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'event.nativeEvent.text'

How do send the 'Event' object to _handleTextChange function?

Thanks,
Yaron

Comment: You should choose an answer as accepted. Good question though. Helped me too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`onChangeText` passes a `string` to your handler function instead of an `Event`.

```
class YourComponent {
   render () {
     // ...
     return <TextInput onChangeText={this._handleTextChange.bind(this)}/>;
   }

  _handleTextChange(text) {
     this.setState({zip: text});
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want an `Event` instead of text `string`, you can use `onChange` instead of `onChangeText`.

```
class YourComponent {
   render () {
     // ...
     return <TextInput onChange={this._handleTextChange.bind(this)}/>;
   }

  _handleTextChange(event) {
     this.setState({zip: event.nativeEvent.text});
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Can you please point me to a website that has the details of each event and what object is passes?

Comment: You're welcome! I looked at [the official document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html). It lacks the details and I had to guess from the examples though.

Comment: If you're interested, you can look at [its source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/508cc06565c1a2ab6ec88dbb8d40d3a2962c198c/Libraries/Components/TextInput/TextInput.js#L699-L701).